# Pymongo access specific field value within nested dict

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

In Pymongo application, while iterating through every document of the collection, how to access a specific field value of the JSON structure?

```
{
  "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e1c2b0bacbdaehujjjbdsh"
       },
  "a": {
        "data_type": "abc",
        "data_format": "xyz",
        "data_version": "1",
       },
  "b": "123",
  "c": "345"
}
```

Based on the following code snippet, how do I access the value associated with the key 'data_format' which is nested within the key 'a' ---

```
  for document in col.find():
      data_format_val = document['a']['data_format']  # not working
```

Relatively new to Mongodb query commands.

Comment: find returns array `document[0]['a']['data_format']` or use findOne

Comment: correct. however I cannot use findOne because I need 'data_format' value for every document of the collection.

Comment: Your code snippet looks correct, assuming that structure is the same for every record in the collection. What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that some of the documents of the collection may not have the key 'a'.

Try using $exists to make sure the field is present like this: Syntax: { field: { $exists:  } }